# Facebook Connect Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

i try to do a Facebook login in localhost and face some problems.

First of all, i use Codeigniter. In order to do Facebook Login, in library, i extracted Facebook SDK, which includes Facebook,base_facebook and fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt.

Then i decided to create a Facebook_Model.php under models directory which is:

```
<?php
class Facebook_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $config = array(
                        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        'fileUpload' => true, // Indicates if the CURL based @ syntax for file uploads is enabled.
                        );

        $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

        // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
        //
        // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
        // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
        // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
        $profile = null;
        if($user)
        {
            try {
                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,email');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }
        }

        $fb_data = array(
                        'me' => $profile,
                        'uid' => $user,
                        'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                            array(
                                'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream', // app permissions
                                'redirect_uri' => 'localhost:81/videoyorum/' // URL where you want to redirect your users after a successful login
                            )
                        ),
                        'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(),
                    );

        $this->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data);
    }
```

}

then i created a controller in order to use my model which is:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Facebook_Model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $fb_data = $this->session->userdata('fb_data');

        print_r($fb_data);


            $data = array(
                'fb_data' => $fb_data,
            );



        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }

}
```

and of course a view:

```
<body>
<div>
  <?php if(!$fb_data['me']): ?>
  Please login with your FB account: <a href="<?php echo $fb_data['loginUrl']; ?>">login</a>
  <!-- Or you can use XFBML -->
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="100" data-max-rows="1" data-scope="email,user_birthday,publish_stream"></div>
  <?php else: ?>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $fb_data['uid']; ?>/picture" alt="" class="pic" />
  <p>Hi <?php echo $fb_data['me']['name']; ?>,<br />
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('topsecret'); ?>">You can access the top secret page</a> or <a href="<?php echo $fb_data['logoutUrl']; ?>">logout</a> </p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]

i wondered that what fb_data prints :

```
Array ( [me] => [uid] => 0 [loginUrl] => https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=localhost%3A81%2Fvideoyorum%2F&state=XXXXXXXXXXX&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cpublish_stream [logoutUrl] => https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81%2Fvideoyorum%2F&access_token=XXXXXXXXX%XXXXXXXXXX)
```

XXXX part includes keys .

i copied this info and paste it to my browser. It gives same error.

These are my fb apps settings:
[image]

What's going wrong ? What causes to error ?

Comment: Have you tried by only keeping your local ip or localhost without port in site url? Is there any records in error log?

Comment: Also why using a Model to get the Facebook user status and info?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
localhost:81/videoyorum/
```

in your $fb_data_array to be

```
http://localhost:81/videoyorum
```

Or, if that doesn't work, try using a non-local server (get a web hosting provider).

Answer (score 0):

change your localhost name to domain name.because facebook app doesn't support localhost address.
`File Path-> C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`
 This is an example of the hosts file
`127.0.0.1  localhost loopback`
`::1        localhost`
`127.0.0.1       localhost`
`127.0.0.1  facebooktest.com`
[Read this](http://www.gkdreamz.com/apache-server/how-to-change-your-default-locahost-name-in-hosts-file/)